# Angular -Store Jquery result in variable

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular

I've a folder structure in Angular component which needs to show the previous state (which folder was open) after the folder structure is reloaded incase of CRUD operation.

[image]

API returns a nested response which is used to create the folder structure using *ngFor.

I tried storing the previous state based on the '.highlight' class to know which folder was open as below

```
//highlight table selection & store the current folder selection
    $('#Table').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event) {
      $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
       sessionStorage.setItem("previousFolder",$(this));
    });
```

but when I try to retrieve the "previousFolder" from session storage & use normal jQuery events like ".find()" ,".parent()" or ".click()" which is not supported since it returns as HTMLelement Object.

which would be the best way to save and restore jQuery results in Angular component?

Comment: localStorage can only contain string values, not objects. You will need to serialise the data you store, most commonly this is done with JSON. I would strongly suggest you do not store an entire jQuery object, though.

Comment: yeah, since i need to find the element again after reload and do normal jquery events on it, hence looking for better solutions too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did store the jQuery result in Angular variable & retrieve it back when needed as below

```
const vm = this; // since jQuery & Angular use same instance of 'this' inside the function
$('#Table').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event) {
      $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
       vm.previousState = $(this);
    });
```

the previousState acts like a normal jQuery selectors with events